# No connectivity between two ubuntu servers

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, networking, server

I have two servers connected like the image i attached here with. I can not ping from the server1 to server2. But I can ping from server1 to R2's Eth1 and server2 can ping R1's Eth1. All other routers can ping each other and to the servers. And no firewall using.

```
==========OS versions==========

Server1:ubuntu 12.04 LTSServer2:ubuntu 16.04 LTS


===========Routing tables of servers.===========
******Server1******
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.10.0.0     *                 255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.10.10.10  192.168.1.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0

(I add last route, but it only works for few times and again connection gone)

******Server2******
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.10.10.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1


========ICMP redirects.=========== 

******Server1******
sysctl -p
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1

******Server2******
sysctl -p
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

[image: Setup]

Comment: What about firewalls? Are there any on either of the servers and, if so, what are their rules?

Comment: No firewalls...not even ufw or iptables.

Comment: As both R1 and R2 are different networks, need to port forward in both modems, right ?

Comment: Yes I had to put a route on a server. Then it is fixed.